# Blazor ComponentBase or Partial Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

Are there any big differences or advantages to using ComponentBase over Partial Class or vice versa in Blazor? I've checked the documentations from Microsoft and so far I didn't get a clear answer. Searching over the internet didn't give me much neither. If there is already a similar question, pointing me to it would be great as well.

Comment: `partial class` is a C# concept, not a Blazor featuer. You can spread the source code of a class over several source files, eg if you want one of them to be auto-generated. Before compilation, all files are merged into one. Your component's code-behind file is a partial class, not a separate or derived class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> differences or advantages to using ComponentBase over Partial Class

Those are not two different or opposite things. You can do both at the same time.

When you add a "code behind class" to for instance the Counter page:

```
// Counter.razor.cs
partial class Counter
{
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

you are using a default rule for partial classes. The above definition is fully equivalent to

```
// Counter.razor.cs
public partial class Counter : ComponentBase 
{
    ... 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fully equivalent"? the code in 1st example doesn't exist in the second. If they are different, then what is the purpose of extending the `Component Base` class?

Comment: That code is summarized with `...`.

Comment: Thanks, I understaand now